# sap.m.MenuItem press event is not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, sapui5

I am using the UI5 `sap.m.Menu` and adding an item to it like this,

```
var menu = new sap.m.Menu();
var deleteItem = new sap.m.MenuItem({
    icon :"sap-icon://delete",
    text : "Delete",
    key : key,
    press: this._onClick.bind(this)
});
```

But here i am not adding any listener to `itemSelect` event from `sap.m.Menu` instead i am using `press` event for `sap.m.MenuItem`. But this `press` event is not triggering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the press event does not really work. Looking over [the code of the MenuItem](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/MenuItem.js) (and the other related classes), it seems that it is never really fired. I opened an issue for the UI5 folks on GitHub: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1505.

As you said, you can use the `itemSelected` event of the Menu instead (until the `press` event is fixed):

```js
var deleteItem = new sap.m.MenuItem({
    icon :"sap-icon://delete",
    text : "Delete",
    key : "delete"
});
var menu = new sap.m.Menu({
    items: [deleteItem],
    itemSelected: function(oE) {
       window.alert("Selected: " + oE.getParameter("item").getKey());
    }
});
```

Working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/93mx0yvt/52/.

Comment: Thanks, Then I have to maintain different key for each of the items. currently, I need to pass some other data along with key also. So if I use press event of the item then I don't have to maintain different keys for different items instead I can directly navigate to the respective item press method in that method I can access the data that I passed as key. Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: You might take a look at the [custom data concept](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f0c3ee6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html). You could use it to attach some more data to the menu item itself and then get it via `oE.getParameter("item").data()`.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use an sap.m.Menu?
There is another type of Menu in OpenUI5: 
[sap.ui.unified.Menu](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.unified.Menu/samples)

Maybe you can use this until the error in sap.m.Menu is fixed